# Scraping dictionary.cambridge.org using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to get link to download mp3 file from *dictionary.cambridge.org*. The correct button has been found by xpath but in no circumstances can I get the link. I was trying to use *.text* and *.get_attribute("href")* methods. Do You have any idea ?   [image]

```
from selenium import webdriver

words=['hunch']
link='https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-polish'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

main_window = driver.current_window_handle
for i in words:
    driver.get(link+"/"+str(i))
    try:
        content = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="entryContent"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/span/span[2]/span[1]/span[2]')
        print(content)
      # print(content.text)
    except:
        driver.close()
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `url` to retrieve the link from the *data-src-mp3* attribute you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following line of code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# lines of code
content = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='circle circle-btn sound audio_play_button uk']")))
print(content.get_attribute("data-src-mp3"))
```

Console Output :

```
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/media/english-polish/uk_pron/u/ukh/ukhun/ukhunch001.mp3
```

Comment: Done. As I see it's not possible to download that file using Selenium.

Comment: IMO, it's possible to download that file using Selenium but you may consider to raise a new ticket for this question.